# How can I make the first character of the dropdown value be deleted if it is a blank space? Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a fairly extensive logic. this is only an example. That's why I need to do something from the view. What ideas can you give me to do it or something simpler not to do it from the controller.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model='zoo' id='zoo' name='animal'  
ng-options="item as item.animal for item in animals  track by item.animal">
</select>
```

my idea is more or less

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model='zoo' id='contrato_objetivo' name='animal'  
ng-options="item as item.animal.charAt(0)==" "?item.animal.substr(1):item.animal for item in animals  track by item.animal">
```

in the view, how can I delete the first character if it has an initial space?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3g2pmrom/

thank you!

Comment: having data properly set is the job of the service layer, your service layer should trim that before sending back them to the controller using the chaining of promises

Comment: You can do it in ng-init="(animals[0].animal === ' ')?animals.splice(0,1):''"

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a filter which means you are not touching the controller, this will help.

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modal) {
        $scope.obj={ };
    $scope.animals=[{"animal":" cat"},{"animal":"dog"}];


}).filter('removespace', function () {
    return function (val) {
        return (!val) ? '' : val.replace(/ /g, '');
    };
});
```

html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model='zoo' id='contrato_objetivo' name='animal'  ng-options="item as item.animal for item in animals  track by item.animal | removespace">
              <option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/eaknm1yh/

the value of the option will be with no space.